# Grab values of object inside an object

Tags: javascript

I am returning a single Object with a nested object, how do I grab the value of the nested object. I want to grab the values of the products list.

```
{
"status":"Processing","_id":"xx234455",
"products":[
{"_id":"5f81a7988289330","name":"ball ","price":70000,
 }],
"returns":20000,"transaction_id":16855
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either iterate it through with `.forEach()` of `products` array or accessing elements by index:

```js
const data = {"status":"Processing","_id":"xx234455","products":[{"_id":"5f81a7988289330","name":"ball ","price":70000,}],"returns":20000,"transaction_id":16855}

// iterate
data.products.forEach(e => console.log(e._id))

// by index
console.log(data.products[0]._id)
```

See from the documentation of [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> The forEach() method executes a provided function once for each array element.

See also the documentation of [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) the ***Access an Array item using the index position*** section.

---

In ***React*** as the tags are suggesting see also with [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as:

```
return <>
   {
      data && data.products &&
      data.products.map((e, i) => <span key={i}>{e._id}</span>)
   }
</>
```

Especially for array usage I suggest to read [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) from React documentation.